# Erlang process pool

Tags: erlang, multiprocessing

I am coming from Java and I am trying to create a process pool in Erlang.

Like the Java API:

```
ThreadPoolExecutor(int corePoolSize, int maximumPoolSize, long keepAliveTime, TimeUnit unit, BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue, RejectedExecutionHandler handler)
```

I can define core threads, time to kill thread, and policy to discard/reject tasks. I created some code in Erlang and it was working, but I am not confident about it.

**The questions:**

1. Am I using it correctly?
2. Any potential bugs in the code?
3. How can I optimize the code?

```
-module(worker_pool).
-export([ init/0, add_job/1]).

-define(TIMEOUT, 6000).
-define(POOL, pool).
-define(MAX, 3).

init() ->
   ets:new(?POOL, [public, named_table, ordered_set]),
   Pid = spawn(?MODULE, controller, []),
   register(?MODULE, Pid).

 %% add job to pool by sending message.
add_job(Value) ->
   ?MODULE ! {new_worker, Value}.

worker() ->
   receive
      {do_work, Value} ->
      example(Value);
    _ ->
      exit(no_valid)
    after ?TIMEOUT ->
        io:format("I (worker ~p) will die now ...~n", [self()]),
      exit(no_activity)
   end.

  %% create pool of process and trigger it by message.
  controller() ->
    receive
      {new_worker, Value} ->
        Pid = insert_job(),
        Pid ! {do_work, Value},
       controller();
    {'DOWN', _Ref, process, Pid, Reason} ->
       io:format(" worker ~p died (~p)~n", [Pid, Reason]),
        delete_job(Pid),
        controller();
    Msg ->
       io:format(" Controller ~p ~n", [Msg]),
        controller()
  end.

 %% internal functions.
   example(Value) ->
      timer:sleep(2000),
     io:format("sleep [~p] done ~n", [Value]).

%% insert to ets table, ordered by time.
  insert_job() ->
     Jobs = ets:info(?POOL, size),
      insert_job(Jobs, ?MAX).
   insert_job(Jobs, Max) when Jobs < Max ->
          {Pid, _} = spawn_monitor(fun() -> worker() end),
           ets:insert(?POOL, {{erlang:monotonic_time(seconds), pid_to_list(Pid)}, []}),
            Pid;
     insert_job(_Jobs, _Max) ->
           First = ets:first(?POOL),
          {_, Key} = First,
          exit(list_to_pid(Key), cancelled),
          ets:delete(?POOL, First),
            {Pid, _} = spawn_monitor(fun() -> worker() end),
            ets:insert(?POOL, {{erlang:monotonic_time(seconds), pid_to_list(Pid)}, []}),
            Pid.

    %% delete job from the pool if it was finished.
    delete_job(Pid) ->
     Pid_list = pid_to_list(Pid),
     ets:match_delete(?POOL, {{'_', Pid_list}, '_'}).`
```

Comment: usually in Erlang process pool create with OTP, for example look [hottub] (https://github.com/bfrog/hottub) . Btw, several questions on your implementation - why ets table and why do the functions of the controller and workers exported?

Comment: @Kvaz1r thanks for your comments.  the reason for `ets` was to limit the generated process.  `Queue` was also considered here, but I still need a ets table to store the queue.       agreed with you,  `controller` and  `workers` should not be exported.

Comment: good, however in this case you can't use spawn/3 it's only for exported functions. Use register(?MODULE, spawn(fun()-> controller() end )) instead.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, the implementation is normal,but something in the code can be simplified:

1.
ets can store any type of Erlang including Pid, it makes no sense to convert to list and back

2.
Remove code duplication in insert_job
endure in a separate function actually added to the table:

```
insert_job() ->
  {Pid, _} = spawn_monitor(fun() -> worker() end),
  ets:insert(?POOL, {{erlang:monotonic_time(seconds), Pid}, []}),
  Pid.
```

3.
Even more unload of function insert job , for that creating a new function to remove the first task:

```
remove_first_job() ->
  First = ets:first(?POOL),
  {_, Key} = First,
  exit(Key, cancelled),
  ets:delete(?POOL, First).
```

4. Rewrite called from controller() insert_job so that to remove the guard expression.

Putting it all together, we get:

```
-module(worker_pool).
-export([init/0, add_job/1]).

-define(TIMEOUT, 6000).
-define(POOL, pool).
-define(MAX, 3).

init() ->
  ets:new(?POOL, [public, named_table, ordered_set]),
  register(?MODULE, spawn(fun() -> controller() end)).

%% add job to pool by sending message.
add_job(Value) ->
  ?MODULE ! {new_worker, Value}.

worker() ->
  receive
    {do_work, Value} ->
      example(Value);
    _ ->
      exit(no_valid)
  after ?TIMEOUT ->
    io:format("I (worker ~p) will die now ...~n", [self()]),
    exit(no_activity)
  end.

%% create pool of process and trigger it by message.
controller() ->
  receive
    {new_worker, Value} ->
      Pid = insert_job(ets:info(?POOL, size), ?MAX),
      Pid ! {do_work, Value},
      controller();
    {'DOWN', _Ref, process, Pid, Reason} ->
      io:format(" worker ~p died (~p)~n", [Pid, Reason]),
      delete_job(Pid),
      controller();
    Msg ->
      io:format(" Controller ~p ~n", [Msg]),
      controller()
  end.

%% internal functions.
example(Value) ->
  timer:sleep(2000),
  io:format("sleep [~p] done ~n", [Value()]).

%% insert to ets table, ordered by time.
insert_job(?MAX, ?MAX) ->
  remove_first_job(),
  insert_job();
insert_job(_, _) ->
  insert_job().

remove_first_job() ->
  First = ets:first(?POOL),
  {_, Key} = First,
  exit(Key, cancelled),
  ets:delete(?POOL, First).

insert_job() ->
  {Pid, _} = spawn_monitor(fun() -> worker() end),
  ets:insert(?POOL, {{erlang:monotonic_time(seconds), Pid}, []}),
  Pid.

%% delete job from the pool if it was finished.
delete_job(Pid) ->
  ets:match_delete(?POOL, {{'_', Pid}, '_'}).
```

Among other things would be good to add a check, for example, correctly handle the call add_job/1 before call init/0 and realize opportunity the stop with the unregistered of process.

As mentioned earlier in the comments, usually in Erlang process pool create with OTP, for example look [hottub](http://github.com/bfrog/hottub).